# SplicedDistribution - different definition across Mathematica 9?

Tags: distributions

I am having troubles with my notebook. I succesfully defined Asymmetric Laplace Distribution at school using `SplicedDistribution` function, and *Mathematica* was able to compute (about 30sec) `Mean`, `Variance`, `Skewness` and `Kurtosis`.
Now, I am at home and *Mathematica* can compute only `Mean`?! I am running *Mathematica 9.0.1.0 Student Edition*. Where is the problem during switching machines? I can make upload of notebook if needed.
[image: SplicedDistribution problem]

```
AsymmetricLaplaceDistribution[ θ_, τ_, κ_] = 
  SplicedDistribution[{ κ, 1/κ},{ -∞, θ, ∞},{ LaplaceDistribution[ θ, τ κ],
                                              LaplaceDistribution[ θ, τ/κ]}];
```

and then

```
ALD = AsymmetricLaplaceDistribution[ θ, τ, κ];
```

and after

```
{ Mean[ALD], Variance[ALD], Skewness[ALD], Kurtosis[ALD]}
```

yields (but only @ school computers? why?)

```
{ θ + τ/κ - κ τ, ((1 + κ^4) τ^2)/κ^2, 
 -(( 2 (-1 + κ^6) τ^3)/(κ^3 (((1 + κ^4) τ^2)/κ^2)^(3/2))),
  (9 + 6 κ^4 + 9 κ^8)/(1 + κ^4)^2}
```

**Edit**: I just find `Moment[ dist, r]` works fine up to `r = 10` what I tested. But still, `Variance` does not.

Comment: What is the version of *Mathematica* @ school ?

Comment: version 9 as well.

Comment: 9.0.0 or 9.0.1 ?

Comment: not sure now, but i dont see anything important on changelog http://www.softpedia.com/progChangelog/Mathematica-Changelog-228323.html

Comment: Well, figure it out - if there's a bug that has not been fixed, would you read about it in the changelog ?

Comment: but I have at home 9.0.1.0, the latest. Do you think it is possible that the bug was created with introducing new features in 9.0.0.0 -> 9.0.1.0? I am not going to school today, but asap I will find out release used.

Comment: We are just playing the guessing game here, but it is possible ..

Comment: We have 9.0.0.0 at school, it works here again now and it looks that its the reason.

Comment: You can submit a report to WRI explaining the situation :)

Comment: @Lukas: For what it's worth: *Mathematica* 10.0.2.0 still does not compute `Variance`, `Skewness` and `Kurtosis`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is partially solved by using functions **MixtureDistribution** and twice **TruncatedDistribution** instead, this is actually how **SplicedDistribution** should be definen, the only non-important change in code is multiplication of tau by 1/sqrt(2).

**In[48] needs some time for symbolical computation, around 90sec on Core i7.**

[image: solution]

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to define **ALD** in following way. This code works in **Mathematica 10.0.0.0**
You can also you **EstimatedDistribution** of **FindDistributionParameters**
[image: screeshot]